# Spring MockMVC defaults wrong ContentType in Response

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test, mockmvc, spring-test-mvc

I've just updated my application to use **spring-test 5.3.12** and **Junit 5.7.2** but now my test are failing.

With the previous version (5.2.X) the response type always was **'application/json'** but now I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Content type expected:<application/json> but 
was:<application/json;charset=UTF-8>
Expected :application/json
Actual   :application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

**I've  checked that the content Type** on the response is, in fact, **application/json** with Postman, Browser and Swagger

Failing test example

```
@Test
void whenGetReleaseNotesAppVersionWithNoExistingCodeThenNotFoundInJsonFormat() throws Exception {
    this.mvc.perform(get(
            NEWER_RELEASES_PATH_UPDATE_CONFIG + "/"
                    + "6.0.0" + "/notes")
                        .header(AUTH_HEADER, AUTH_TOKEN_SRVCGERETDESAX)
                        .locale(Locale.ENGLISH)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isNotFound())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(jsonPath(
                "$.code", is(ApiErrorCode.RELEASE_NOTES_NOT_FOUND.getCode())));
}
```

Can't change MediaType to **APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8** because is now **deprecated**, so I can't figure out how fix this.

MockMVC is just autowired, without further configuration

```
   @Autowired
   private MockMvc mvc;
```

Annotations in class

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = {
        Application.class })
@ActiveProfiles({ "test" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class UpdateConfigControllerIT {...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either declare the fully expected content type by adding the charset:

```java
.andExpect(content().contentType(new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
```

or use [`contentTypeCompatibleWith`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/ContentResultMatchers.java#L102):

```java
.andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

*Just a small note; you can safely remove the `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` annotation as the [`@SpringBootTest`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.java#L81) annotation is already meta-annotated with the given annotation.*

Comment: Thank you, both seems to work as workaround. But I'm still wondering why MockMVC changes his behaviour and start returning the charset along the contentType since the 5.3.0 version. Is any problem with my configuration?